# pushing the changes causing huge number objects to push

Tags: git

I'm having strange issue, when I'm trying to push the changes from my local repository to remote repository, sometimes (and it's happening a lot), git is acting like existing branches are not recognized and it tries to push all objects (20.000+ of them), even I made a change on only 2 of them, and from the state 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Sample:

```
me@my-desktop:~/repo/project/$ git push origin feature/myFeature 
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/tags/
  refs/heads/
  refs/heads/feature/
updating 'refs/heads/feature/myFeature'
  from 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  to   161612d12a7a474fda294036e34c268131dbcb04
    sending 21322 objects
```

UPDATED: I use git flow and features for branching.

Comment: Use a colon instead of a slash: `git push origin branch:myExistingBranch`

Comment: I got this error when I try that one:
    error: src refspec feature does not match any.

Comment: Perhaps what you wanted to do was this: `git push origin myExistingBranch:myExistingBranchOnOrigin`

Comment: Maybe my example confuses you. I use flow, and the branch is feature branch, with name myFeature, so in this case branch/myExistingBranch is feature/myFeature. I will update my question.

Comment: What protocol are you using?  (The above does not resemble ssh output at all.)

Comment: @torek Don't know about jMn, but I'm having same problem sometimes with webDAV (origin like http://some.host.fqdn/~myuser/myDir.git) using git 1.7.10.4 (from Debian Wheezy) on both sides. And that is pure commit-by-commit which should fast-forward, no branches or featuures. I add one new commit, and 'push' starts from '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' and takes ages. And other times it just correctly pushes one or two new commits, no problem. Could "git gc" on either side (which packs commits) be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @MatijaNalis: using that, plus comments in http-push.c, I provided a possible answer.  Don't know if it's correct, but you are welcome to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using http pushes (with DAV), I note the following in http-push.c in the git sources:

```
/*
 * NEEDSWORK: remote_ls() ignores info/refs on the remote side.  But it
 * should _only_ heed the information from that file, instead of trying to
 * determine the refs from the remote file system (badly: it does not even
 * know about packed-refs).
 */
```

If this comment is accurate, the problem is that the remote has packed the target reference, and (as the comment notes) the push can't find the ref so it's sending every single object.

Thus, as [Matija Nalis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689663/pushing-the-changes-causing-huge-number-objects-to-push?noredirect=1#comment33810040_19689663) suggested in a comment, `git gc` on the receiving side has led to the problem.  You could test this by re-creating the unpacked ref on the receiver:

```
cd (path to repo .git directory)
(verify that refs/heads/branch does not exist)
awk '$2 == "refs/heads/branch" { print $1 }' packed-refs
```

(write resulting line, assuming there is one, to `refs/heads/branch`, and then try the push).

As I don't use web push, I can't verify this myself.

Answer (score 0):

That error should be fixed with Git 2.28 (Q3 2020): the code to push changes over "dumb" HTTP had a bad interaction with the **commit reachability** code due to incorrect allocation of object flag bits, which has been corrected.

See [commit 64472d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64472d15e90f14d920eade6bb1d1c4a01fca2280) (23 Jun 2020) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 67d99b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67d99b82de27e98bfec7d174ef4b6369d5b85d7a), 06 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`http-push`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64472d15e90f14d920eade6bb1d1c4a01fca2280): ensure unforced pushes fail when data would be lost
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Michael Ward</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> When we push using the [DAV-based protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAV), the client is the one that performs the ref updates and therefore makes the checks to see whether an unforced push should be allowed.
>
> We make this check by determining if either
>
> - (a) we lack the object file for the old value of the ref or
> - (b) the new value of the ref is not newer than the old value,
>
> and in either case, reject the push.
>
> However, the `ref_newer` function, which performs this latter check, has an odd behavior due to the reuse of certain object flags.
>
> Specifically, it will incorrectly return false in its first invocation and then correctly return true on a subsequent invocation.
>
> This occurs because the object flags used by [`http-push.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/64472d15e90f14d920eade6bb1d1c4a01fca2280/http-push.c) are the same as those used by [`commit-reach.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/64472d15e90f14d920eade6bb1d1c4a01fca2280/commit-reach.c), which implements `ref_newer,` and one piece of code misinterprets the flags set by the other.
>
> Note that this does not occur in all cases.
>
> For example, if the example used in the tests is changed to use one repository instead of two and rewind the head to add a commit, the test passes and we correctly reject the push.
>
> However, the example provided does trigger this behavior, and the code has been broken in this way since at least Git 2.0.0.
>
> To solve this problem, let's move the two sets of object flags so that they don't overlap, since we're clearly using them at the same time. The new set should not conflict with other usage because other users are either builtin code (which is not compiled into [`git http-push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-push)) or `upload-pack` (which we similarly do not use here).